# FactoryBot one record associated with many attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have `User`, `Assignment` and `Department` models.
My `Assignment` model has 2 `belongs_to` associations with the `User` model as `requestor` and `assignee`.

The `User` and `Assignment` model also in turn `belongs_to` a department.

I want to run a validation on my `Assignment` such that the `assignment`, `requestor` and `assignee` all belong to the same department.

This is my code for the models

```
# app/models/assignment.rb
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :requestor, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "requested_by"
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "assigned_to"

  belongs_to :department
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_departments, class_name: "UserDepartment"
  has_many :departments, through: :user_departments

  belongs_to :department
end

# app/models/department.rb
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_departments, class_name: "UserDepartment"
  has_many :users, through: :user_departments

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users
end
```

This is the code for my test

```
# spec/factories/assignment.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  sequence(:title) { |n| "Title #{n}" }
  sequence(:description) { |n| "Description #{n}" }

  factory :assignment do
    title
    description
    image { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/support/Floyd.jpeg'), 'image/jpeg') }
    release_date { DateTime.now >> 1 }
    department { create(:department) }
    requestor create(:user, :bm, department: "I want to use the same department as created in earlier line here")
    assignee create(:user, :mu, department: "I want to use the same department as created in earlier line here")
  end
end
```

Where should I define the department so I can use the same department across all three associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `self.department`? It worked in my code:

```
# spec/factories/assignment.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  sequence(:title) { |n| "Title #{n}" }
  sequence(:description) { |n| "Description #{n}" }

  factory :assignment do
    title
    description
    image { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/support/Floyd.jpeg'), 'image/jpeg') }
    release_date { DateTime.now >> 1 }
    department { create(:department) }
    requestor { create(:user, :bm, department: self.department) }
    assignee { create(:user, :mu, department: self.department) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @MrShemek. I didn't know you could self reference the factory with self.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I got the question right. You want the same department on all the models.
This is a thing you actually do in the spec.

```
describe Foo::Bar do
  before(:each) do
    @department = create(:deparment)
    @assignment = create(:assignment, department: @department)
    @user = create(:user, department: department)
    # ....
  end
```

But this always depends on how your overall structure is. When the `assignment` is the center model and always has a department you could do something like

```
describe Foo::Bar do
  before(:each) do
    @assignment = create(:assignment)
    @user = create(:user, department: @assignment.department)
    # ....
  end
```

Comment: I wanted to have one complete valid record in my factory, that was why I made all the associations in the assignment. Is this not how it should be done. I'm new to testing and could take a few pointers

Comment: Fixed a copy paste error in the second example. I always did it like this and never have seen it differently. If you build a complex association record and just do `create(:assignment)` at some point it gets confusing since you always have to check back to the factory. So usually a factory is a minimal viable object and gets the necessary relation its need for certain specs so you always know what's going on. Let's say you just want to check if the `assignment.description` is validated correctly there you don't want to build a "complex" relation structure.

Comment: That makes sense. Ill try incorporating what you said in my factories. Thanks for the tip.